# Strip last period from a host string

Tags: python, regex, replace

I am having a hard time figuring out how to strip the last period from a hostname ...

current output:

- domain.com.
- suddomain.com.
- domain.com.
- subdomain.subdomain.com.
- subdomain.com.

desired output:

- domain.com
- subdomain.com
- domain.com
- subdomain.subdomain.com

attempt 1:

```
print string[:-1]  #it works on some lines but not all
```

attempt 2:

```
 str = string.split('.')
 subd = '.'.join(str[0:-1])
 print subd    # does not work at all
```

code:

```
global DOMAINS

if len(DOMAINS) >= 1:
  for domain in DOMAINS:
    cmd = "dig @adonis.dc1.domain.com axfr %s |grep NS |awk '{print $1}'|sort -u |grep -v '^%s.$'" % (domain,domain)
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,   shell=True)
    string = p.stdout.read()
    string = string.strip().replace(' ','')
    if string:
      print string
```

Comment: attempt 1 would work in all your test cases, can you provide an example where it fails?

Comment: print string[:-1] ... fails on all but the very last subdomain

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You do it like this:

```
hostname.rstrip('.')
```

where hostname is the string containing the domain name.

```
>>> 'domain.com'.rstrip('.')
'domain.com'
>>> 'domain.com.'.rstrip('.')
'domain.com'
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer given by @isedev is somewhat incomplete in this specific use case. `rstrip('.')` will strip the trailing period from a string, however the string returned by `subprocess` will have a trailing newline character (0x0A) following the period which causes `rstrip('.')` to fail.

This is likely why OP gave up.

Consider the following python3 code:

```
print ('domain.'.rstrip('.'))
```

Works as perceived. However, adding a newline character to mimic shell output:

```
print ('domain.\n'.rstrip('.'))
```

prints `domain.`

One way to manage this is to simply insert a `strip()` before the `rstrip()` call:

```
print ('domain.\n'.strip().rstrip('.'))
```

which prints: `domain`

Always, always strip your shell output :)

Comment: That's what I did here. Plus you want to `lower()` all domain/host names to avoid problems with some servers. So my first tidy-up chain is: `domain = domain.lower().strip().rstrip(".")`

Answer (score -3):

I gave up and just used sed instead  ....

```
cmd = "dig @adonis.dc1.domain.com axfr %s |grep NS |awk '{print $1}' |sort -u |grep -v '^%s.$'|sed -e 's/.$//'"
```

Comment: @isedev gave you the answer you were looking for (in fact, the simplest one). that should be the accepted answer.